# Is there a way to assign resource into a variable in the inspector programmatically?

Tags: unity

I want to add resource to an inspector directly which could be done by drag and drop resource to the inspector. However, I want to know if there's a programmatic way to do this so, I will not need to add it hand by hand to perform a better performance than Resource.Load()

Comment: Look into custom editors. They should be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ben's suggestion, help me to found an answer.

1. Mark [ExecuteInEditMode] on top of the Monobehavior class that I need to assign var to.
2. Use AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath to load the resource I need into variable type that I want.
3. Save scene.
4. Remove script that add recently if you don't need it in production.